App dev for assurances management, is it haram?
I work as a software engineer and I had a mission: create an application for a company to use to manage its contract assurances with its customers. Like register, delete, modify..... Is it haram ?

Was too long for one comment: ---  Print three more zero digits on every piece of paper money and everyone will have a thousand times the money. But what you can buy for it only Allah can provide, and in history He did that by blessing the working hands of the people.

Why would you think it could be haram? Is it about life insurance? Then you might be irritated about the en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value and its calculation being riba or not. In the time of the Prophet, paying and prices were made by referring to cons made out of gold, silver or copper. I don't know any reference, but my feeling is that constantly debased paper money has not the same rulings on riba than what has been set up for touchable properties, like coins in gold, silver or commodities like wheat or wood to build houses.
